# How can I add another client ID to: <% If Session("ClientID") <> "1044" Then %>

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, client

I want to add another client, in addition to 1044, and avoid breaking the code which is what I assume will happen if I just add another ID number.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Looks like you are reading value from session and compairing, so what is the context, what is that you want to do and doesn't work?

Comment: Sure. The code hides a question on a SaaS employment form for client #1044 so their applicants can't see or need to respond to it. Now client #1126 also wants to hide the same question from their applicants.

Comment: Well your question seems to be too specific to your domain, but this should work - <% If Session(“ClientID”) <> “1044” And Session(“ClientID”) <> “1126” Then %>

Comment: Thanks - great help. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question seems to be too specific to your domain, but this should work -

`<% If Session(“ClientID”) <> “1044” And Session(“ClientID”) <> “1126” Then %>`